# jQuery/Javascript not working on dynamic web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that works completely fine on static web page, but I cannot get it to work on dynamic web pages. I tried different techniques from the research I've done, but I still cannot get it to work, so I'm looking for help.

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mywebsite.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('submit', '#bv-form', function() {

            var data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'notify.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#bv-form").fadeOut(500).hide(function() {
                    $(".form-result").fadeIn(500).show(function() {
                        $(".form-result").html(data);
                    });
                });

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" id="bv-form">
    <div class="checkbox form-feedback margin-five m_top_20">
        <!-- checkbox  -->
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="video_title" id="publish" checked value="<?php echo ucwords($row['video_title']); ?>"> <em>"<?php echo ucwords($row['video_title']); ?>"</em> by <b><?php echo ucwords($row['artist_name']); ?></b> is not working</label>
        <!-- end checkbox  -->
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- button  -->
        <button class="btn btn-black no-margin-bottom btn-small no-margin-top" id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
        <!-- end button  -->
        <input type="hidden" id="id"> 
        <input type="hidden" id="video_id" name="video_id" value="<?php echo ucwords($row['id']); ?>"> 
        <input type="hidden" id="artist_name" name="artist_name" value="<?php echo $row['video_title']; ?>"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm using `.on()`, but is there something I'm missing?

**NOTE:** I know that the question has been asked before on this site. I've tried following certain steps in those solutions, but I still cannot get this script to work.

Comment: How does the HTML look like?

Comment: What part of it is not working?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney When submit is click, the form just reloads.

Comment: @Reeno I've edited my question to show the HTML

Comment: perhaps try checking `$('#bv-from').length` before running your script, might narrow down the problem

Comment: It's possible you've got a PHP error being displayed meaning the browser can't parse the JavaScript within `<script>` tags. Check the console for errors.

Answer (score 2):

If the form is dynamic, meaning it is added to the page after page load, then it's likely the submit will not fire because it can't find the form.

Try this:

```
$(document).find("#bv-form").on('submit', function(){ ... });
```

This searches the DOM for the ID as opposed to assuming it's there

Comment: It still does not work, although I can tell it's trying to do something. The script now looks like this: `$(document).ready(function()
                              { 

                $(document).find("#bv-form").on('submit', function()
                               {


                 ...rest of script`

Comment: This is exactly the same as doing `$('#bv-form').on('submit'...`. OP is using event delegation by attaching the handler to `document` which is correct for dynamically added forms, whereas this will not work unless the form is present in the DOM when it's ready.

Comment: I am getting no errors from the script itself, but I am getting an error message from the Google + button script: `https://plus.google.com/http://mywebsite.com/js/platform.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)` I'm not sure why I'm getting a 404 error. I'm on a live website. I'm not using localhost

Comment: @Soletwosole Look at the URL. That's incorrect, it's got your website as part of the path. The URL should be https://plus.google.com/js/platform.js

Comment: @Andy. Thanks for catching that. The error message pertaining to Google+ is now gone, but the script is just reloading the page. Does SO have private messaging so that I can send you link to the site to show you what's happening?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of...It'd be better to add the link to your question anyway. It's very difficult to answer the question correctly otherwise.